# Issues installing android studio on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, android-studio

I have spent 2 days now trying to research answers, but I seem to be having a different installation issue with Android Studio than others- the 'installer' never runs. Here's the situation:

1. New to Android Studio, fresh install on a Win7 machine. Java JDK 1.8.0_25 installed, JAVA_HOME variable set, JDK_HOME variable set. javac -version returns proper version.
2. I download the .zip file (android-studio-ide-135.1538390-windows) and unzip it per instructions. Next instruction is to launch studio.exe. The only studio.exe I see is in \bin.
   I'm guessing studio64.exe will work under Win7 64bit/ Java 64bit as well.
3. Android Studio launches. No installation wizard or anything.
4. Now that Studio has launched, there are no SDK options. SDK Manager is grayed out. Also, I can't set the SDK directory under Configure-Project Defaults-Project Structure. No directory I point to works. Studio runs but is not able to start new projects.

I have to be missing something painfully obvious, does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I see a newer similar question that has an answer - [Installing new Android studio Beta v.0.8.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764174/installing-new-android-studio-beta-v-0-8-14/26764657#26764657)

Haven't tried it yet, but why wouldn't the Studio download page say you need the SDK as a separate install? The button that downloads the .zip says 'Download Android Studio **WITH** the Android SDK for Windows' right on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem you did. I just went to [this web](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i#download) and clicked on "*GET THE SDK FOR AN EXISTING IDE*". Downloaded the "*Stand-alone Android SDK Tools for Windows*", and installed to a preferred directory.

Relaunched android studio and at the quick settings screen:

`CONFIGURE->PROJECT DEFAULTS->PROJECT STRUCTURE`

and browsed to the location where I installed the SDK

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, from what I understand developer.android.com makes you download the wrong file, you get a zip file without the SDK, which is supposed to be for updating for those who already have the an old version with an SDK installed.

Try going to [this page](http://tools.android.com/download/studio) instead, choose the version you want, and then you can choose to download the full installer instead.

Comment: I can't see full installer link. Is there full installer with sdk bundled available to download?