# Installing new Android studio Beta v.0.8.14

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello I am new in Android development

So as suggested by google I downloaded the latest October 2014 beta version of Android Studio to start developing because they will end up solely with the Android Studio IDE so I thing it is a good idea to get used of it...

To install they just give you a zip file. I unzipped it and followed the text instructions which were simple BUT I cannot find the files and folders the say should exist in their unzipped folder/files :s .

The instructions are 
'' To set up Android Studio on Windows:

Unzip the file, android-studio-ide--windows.zip and launch the studio.exe file.
Follow the setup wizard to install Android Studio and the SDK Tools.
On some Windows systems, the launcher script does not find where Java is installed. If you encounter this problem, you need to set an environment variable indicating the correct location.
Select Start menu > Computer > System Properties > Advanced System Properties. Then open Advanced tab > Environment Variables and add a new system variable JAVA_HOME that points to your JDK folder, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21. ''

Although I find the studio.exe at the path \android-studio-ide-135.1538390-windows\android-studio\bin

I cannot find any kind of a setup wizard for the SDK Tools!!
When I start the studio.exe program and I go to Configure/Project Defaults/Project Structure 
the java sdk has been found but the android sdk folder naturally it is not.
And also the Configure/SDK Manager is not enabled.

What obvious thing am I missing here?? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you downloaded `android-studio-ide-135.1538390-windows`, then it only contains the IDE and not the Android SDK. You need to download it separately:

> http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe

[link](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i)

You will then point Android Studio to your SDK installation location.

Comment: well it does say "Download Android studio Beta v0.8.14 with the Android SDK for Windows" on the blue button

Comment: I am also just struggling to find a proper installer for my new PC.
I can not remember having so much work with the previous android studio. Now all you get is a blank "October" ZIP file without SDK (the link lies) or anything else. 
Google seems to try to kill their new IDE baby now.