# Android studio download - nothing happening after some time

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I was downloading Android Studio and once it had finished, I decided to run it. On running Android Studio, it stops here nothing happens after it. Are there any prerequisites to be followed?

I have java JDK 8 and I tried to change the download location but nothing helped.

The error screen-

[image: Error where Android Studio got stuck]

Comment: I tried to install it recently, but also failed somewhere at the SDK-installation.

Comment: As far as I can see, Android Studio is still trying to download files.

Comment: @Rohan- It has been 45-50 minutes but nothing has happened.

Comment: So you are saying that it is stuck while downloading? That might be a connection issue. You can also try to download the SDK manually and use it.

Comment: @Rohan -  I dont know how to use it manually. Can you help me with it?

Comment: @yushi has specified the answer, if you still need help then post a comment, I'll try to add some image tutorial.

Comment: @RohanKandwal - I have downloaded the stand alone SDK tools. Now where should i install them? Do I need to set system variables?

Comment: @RohanKandwal..Thanks a lot :D..My android studio is now working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues installing android studio on windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761569/issues-installing-android-studio-on-windows-7)